# Why is the domain of this implicit function all $x\in R$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Function:**

> $$x^2-\sin^{-1}y=\frac \pi2$$

A simple [WolframAlpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain%20of%20x%5E2-arcsin(y)%3Dpi%2F2) outputs that its domain is:

$$D=\{(x,y)\in R^2:y\in[-1,1]\}$$

I understand $y$ is restricted due to $\sin^{-1}y$, but I have trouble understanding why $x$ is *unrestricted*. The following logic makes me believe $x$ should be *restricted*:

Since $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac\pi2+\sin^{-1}y}$, and $\sin^{-1}y\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$, so, $\color{blue}{x\in[-\sqrt{\pi},\sqrt{\pi}]}$.

I don't exactly see the fault in my reasoning. Can anyone elaborate the reason for this anomaly?

**Note**: on that WA page, the "Input interpretation" box clearly says that it is finding the domain of $x^2-\sin^{-1}y=\frac \pi2$ and NOT $f(x,y)=x^2-\sin^{-1}y$ as was initially proposed by @HansLundmark.

**UPDATE:** added additional notes from discussion in comments. Corrected final answer thanks to @ziprovich.

Comment: Well, Wolfram probably takes sin$^{-1}$ to be multivalued as $\sin x= \sin(x+2\pi)$.

Comment: @marmot Possibly correct, but I don't see any evidence for the same. The [graph for $\sin^{-1}x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=arcsin+x) has correct domain and range. The [Wolfram language docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcSin.html) also give no hint at $\sin^{-1}$ being multivalued.

Comment: It's not clear to me what question the “domain of” command is actually trying to answer. If you remove “=pi/2” from the query, you get the same answer. Could it be that WA is simply giving the domain of the function $f(x,y)=x^2-\arcsin y$?

Comment: Also note that there's a mistake in your reasoning. Knowing $x^2=\text{value}$ does **NOT** imply that $x=\sqrt{\text{value}}$.

Comment: @zipirovich Thanks for your input! Yes, you're right, it should have been $x=\pm\sqrt{\text{value}}$ instead...

Comment: @HansLundmark But, do note one thing, on that WA webpage, the "Input interpretation" box clearly says that it is finding the domain of $x^2-\sin^{-1}y=\frac\pi2$ and NOT $f(x,y)=x^2-\sin^{-1}y$ as you thought.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't really know what that's supposed to *mean* to begin with. I know what the domain of a *function* is, but I've never seen a definition of the concept “domain of an *equation*”.

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, that also confused me as well. I assumed it that all possible $x,y$ values which can satisfy the given equation are its domain.

Answer (score 0):

The function $sin^{-1}$ is defined on $[-1,1]$, so $y\in [-1,1]$. The function $F(x,y)=x^2-sin^{-1}y$ is defined on $\mathbb R \times [-1,1]$, but if you want to find the domain in which the equation $F(x,y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ has solutions, then $x^2\in [0,\pi]$, hence $x\in [-\sqrt \pi, \sqrt \pi]$.

Note $x^2=a\geq 0 \Rightarrow x=\pm \sqrt a$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is also relevant to what I had got as my answer. It will be more helpful though, if you could also elaborate why WolframAlpha thinks the domain for $x$ is all real. Thank you!

Comment: I don't used WolframAlpha, but my guess is that it only gives the domain of definition for the function $f(x,y)=x^2-sin^{-1}y$, not the domain in which the equation $f(x,y)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ has solutions. I'm sorry, but I cannot help you in this regard.

Comment: Alright, that's completely fine. Thanks for trying to help out, I really appreciate it :)